# Keep hidden element displayed when hover over it

Tags: jquery, hover, show-hide

I had trouble forming a title- please edit if you come up with something better.

When hovering over a span with class `percent100`, I want to show a div with class `getSeen`. However, `getSeen` has a link on it, so `getSeen` has to remain open when the user hovers over `getSeen`, not just `percent100`. How do I do this with jQuery?

HTML:

```
<span class="percent100"> 100%</span>
<div class="getSeen">At 100% Get Seen...<a href="#">How?</a></div>
```

jQuery attempt:

```
$('.percent100, .getSeen').hover(
    function () {
        $('.getSeen').toggle();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use this query

```
$('.percent100, .getSeen').hover(
    function () {
        $('.getSeen').show();
    },
    function () {
        $('.getSeen').hide();
    }
);
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZRCLa/)

So what you need to do is, to make the `div.getSeen` visible when the `.percent100` is hovered and also when `.getSeen` is hovered, and simply make it invisible when hoverout